# How to calculate Odds Ratio and Risk Ratio in R

Tags: r

I am new to R

The data I have is attached as a google sheet. Its a small part of data. data has 12274 rows and 107 columns

click on link below for data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kpWtAxj7XTNaXowMjBsZ5lWm6LlbdE2nzH6s6Pll1Y8/edit?usp=sharing

I want to calculate odds ration and risk ratio with PH and all other variables one by one.
tried to use this:

```
tab <- table(mydata[[i]],mydata[[j]])
OddsRatio <- epitab(tab,method = "oddsratio")
```

But it does not help.
Please suggest the solution
Thank you in advance

Comment: so based on the binomial case, OR=\frac{\frac{p_1}{1-p_1}}{\frac{p_2}{1-p_2}}. You would need to compute that for all of your data? How would you estimate your probabilities?

Comment: What is the meaning of "it does not help". As `epitab` needs a table, table need factors ! But your data appears to have continue variables. Discretize your variables first (make factors) the do the tabs.

Comment: @Robert Did you mean to convert the data into categories..?
i used this as well at some point of time
tab <- table(cut(mydata[[i]], pretty(mydata[[i]])),mydata[[j]])

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you want, but `vcd::oddsratio` is a good place to start!

```
# load libraries
library(gsheet)
library(vcd)
# load data
df <- gsheet2tbl('docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kpWtAxj7XTNaXowMjBsZ5lWm6LlbdE2nzH6s6Pll1Y8')
# remove NAs
df <- df[,-3]
df <- df[-8,]
# convert to matrix 
mat <- data.matrix(df, rownames.force = NA)
# calculate odds ratio
oddsratio(mat, log = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. But, as the data is huge, I would need a general method to remove the NA`s. And odds ratio is to be calculated for two variables at one time
For ex-  pH -apger score, pH - weight small , pH-weight large and so on

Comment: If you want to find rows with no missing values, you can try `complete.cases(df)`. This gives you a logical vector. If you want a subset of data, keeping only complete cases, you can try `df[complete.cases(df),]`. This can also be done by executing this `na.omit(df)`.